# How to check if a comma seperated column contains the word from comma seprated string

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, query-performance, sqlperformance

I need to know if  words  from comma separated string is available in a comma separated column

suppose a value in table column is 'ram,sham,shanghai' and my search string is
'ram,shanghai'  then i need to select this

Comment: It is possible, but not clean. You can break the search string up in SQL (join the string against a query to return a list of numbers, and use the numbers with SUBSTRING_INDEX() to split the string up into rows), and then you can use FIND_IN_SET() to find them.

Comment: @Kickstart is comment is possible the more cleaner solution would be to normilize the table column. Plus points would be that aggregated/search qeuries are much easier.. Negative point would be that your application code needs to be changed to handle proper table relations instead off comma separated value relations.

Comment: If amending the database and applications to use normalised table design is possible then I would very much recommend it. Failing that it would be better to split up the comma separated string of values to search for before checking on the database.